# High memory usage when uploading and manipulating many files

Tags: javascript, html, filereader, fine-uploader, fileapi

I am trying to use FineUploader to upload a large amount of files. I also need to manipulate the files before uploading them - namely I need to anonymize some identifying information. In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400415/alter-file-contents-before-uploading?rq=1), Ray Nicholus suggested to reject the original file in the onSubmit handler and then re-add the manipulated file. So my onSubmit handler looks like so:

```
onSubmit: function (id, name)
{
    var file = this.getFile(id)
    if (file.isAnonymized)
    {
        return;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = function()
    {
        var arrayBuffer = this.result
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)
        // Manipulate the byteArray in some way...
        var blob = new window.Blob([byteArray])
        blob.isAnonymized = true
        // add the anonymized file instead
        uploader.addFiles({blob: blob, name: name})
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
    // cancel the original file
    return false
},
```

This works fine for a small amount of files. In a concrete example, a customer tried to upload ~1.500 files of 3MB each in Firefox, and saw Firefox's memory usage spike through the roof before the tab eventually crashed. Other browsers (Chrome, Edge) exhibit similar behavior. Using the browser's developer tools doesn't seem to show any large memory allocations. There are no problems when simply uploading the files as-is, but that's not an option.

Comment: You might think about putting it into a WebWorker somehow.

Comment: Some js file library are not designed to manage a lot of file. XMLHttpRequest are huge and async object. Usually, this kind of library starts all uploads in a for loop which hangs the browser when you put more than ~1000 files (because it allocates and tries to start 1000 simultaneous connections). I suggest to you to write your own upload part.

Comment: Like I said, simply uploading works like a charm, so I'm pretty confident that's not the problem. It's when I need to manipulate the files beforehand that the pain starts.

Comment: Another thing I tried is to upload the files in batches of 10 each so the browser wouldn't open 100 files at the same time. That didn't solve the problem

Comment: `uploader.addFiles(...)` => Does it clear correctly added files after upload?

Comment: @SantiagoGarcia My understanding is you may have all 1500 files (in your example) being processed simultaneously in your `onSubmit` handler. Is this an accurate assumption?

Comment: @RayNicholus Yeah, I noticed that myself, which is why I changed it to add 10 files at a time - memory usage still spikes, particularly in Firefox.

I uploaded the full example at https://github.com/sgarcialaguna-mms/file-upload-memory which uses Sinon to fake a server.

Comment: Yes, memory will spike since you are managing these files in memory.

Comment: By spike I meant "grows and grows until the tab eventually crashes".

Are you saying I should try with an actual webserver instead of faking it with Sinon?

Comment: For every file you manage in memory, as you are doing in your example code, browser memory will grow until the Blob objects you are creating are eligible for GC. This is never an issue for files that are simply accessed from the filesystem and uploaded, since those are stored on disk, not in memory. But once you start reading files as you are doing, you need to be conscious of memory impact.

Comment: Okay, I understand that much. I also understand how the initial code I posted can read in all the files at once and have changed that in my example (yes, it's quick and dirty, I know).  I'm still not clear on how to get from my example code at https://github.com/sgarcialaguna-mms/file-upload-memory to a version that allows the blobs to be garbage collected after they have been successfully uploaded.

Comment: Okay, calling reset() on the uploader before adding the new batch of files seems to help. I'm not sure if that would be the "best" way of doing it, but at least it's a way.

Comment: Doubt that `reset` will solve your problem. Likely a red herring. Objects are available for GC when they have no references to them. When will GC actually happen once that is true? That's up to the browser.

Also I guess I'm not sure where your memory issue is. Is it file bytes, or something else? You'll need to investigate further if you don't have definitive proof.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up the example at https://github.com/sgarcialaguna-mms/file-upload-memory/ somewhat and am now confident that the error is due to the fineuploader library holding on to blobs longer than needed.

The example now loads one file into memory at a time, then passes the blob to the upload library. I also now use an actual server (the Django example from the fineuploader server-examples repository).

With Firefox, when I drag in ~1GB of files, Firefox's memory usage steadily rises during the upload and stays high even after the upload is completed. I can open about:memory, click "Minimize memory usage" to trigger a garbage collection, press on "Measure" and the file data shows up under "memory-file-data/large". Call `uploader.reset()`, trigger a garbage collection again and  Firefox's memory usage drops sharply. Measuring again shows the "memory-file-data/large" objects are no longer present in memory. As per https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1540#issuecomment-194201646, calling `this._handler.expunge(id)` after every upload works as well.

Chrome behaves a bit differently, due to a long-standing bug it eventually starts throwing ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND errors once more than 500 MB of blob data accumulates. The chrome://blob-internals page shows which blobs are being held as well as their refcount.

I don't know if there is an easy way to tell which variable / closure / whatever is holding on to these objects, but it would help immensely.

Comment: Files do not consume memory, they are backed by disk. Holding onto these files will not consume memory. However, if you are passing in Blobs that are not backed by files on disk, that is a different story. I'm not aware of any area where Fine Uploader would be holding onto these blobs longer than necessary. In order to be confident that this is the case, the code will need to be explored and a reference to where the issue lies will need to be uncovered.

Comment: Most likely, the issue is in your code. If you are passing 1 GB of memory-backed Blobs to Fine Uploader, of course this will consume 1 GB of memory, and the blobs must stay in scope until they have been uploaded.

Comment: Ok, last comment from me as I won't have internet access for the rest of the year.

@RayNicholus "Most likely, the issue is in your code. If you are passing 1 GB of memory-backed Blobs to Fine Uploader, of course this will consume 1 GB of memory, and the blobs must stay in scope until they have been uploaded." That much is obvious. As I clearly stated, the problem is that the memory is not released after the upload. 

"Most likely, the issue is in your code." My code is right there. It's barely 60 lines. If you can spot a mistake I've made, I'll be happy to hear it.

Comment: It seems we are going in circles on this one. There is no issue, that I am aware of, in Fine Uploader code where blobs are being held onto after upload. If you can point to the code where this is happening, I'd be happy to fix. All Fine Uploader code is publically available. In the absence of actual evidence, and since there are no other such reports, I have to assume the issue is on your end, and that pretty clearly seems to be the issue given the code in your question. Please re-read my comment above, and you'll likely see where the issue lies in your code...

Comment: ...in short, if your user submits 1- 1GB disk-backed file, 1 GB of memory is consumed when your code generates a corresponding memory-backed blob and adds it to the uploader. If your user drops 10- 1 GB disk-backed files, onSubmit will be called for all 10, at once, and your code turns around and submits 10- 1 GB memory-backed blobs, _at once_. If this exceeds available RAM, the tab will crash. In short, you'll need to _not_ do this and meter your creation of memory-backed blobs. Your answer verifies what I have said here.

Comment: @RayNicholus Yes, the onSubmit handler in my question is wrong in the way you described. You are 100% correct about that.

But I've acknowledged that way back on Dec 8 and changed my example accordingly - I load in _one_ file at a time, pass the blob to the uploader, then proceed to the next file after the upload has completed. I don't even use the onSubmit callback anymore. However, I can still reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please file an issue in the project's issue tracker so we can discuss possible causes a bit more in-depth. SO is more for support questions.